# jquery image auto slide

Tags: jquery, image

How to make an image to slide and navigation button to cycle image from right to left jquery.where  images are in the div element,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us more to go on.  Some example code?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use [Cycle Lite](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/).
It's a very tiny slider plugin for jQuery which allows you to make amazing slides very easily.
It's also very nicely documented. Just check it out!

Edit: Now there's [Orbit](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) from Foundation.js which uses HTML5 and is compatible with touch devices.

Answer (score 1):

http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

First google result. Should be what you are searching. 15 Slideshows.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of jQuery's animate() functionality to provide custom animation.If all you have to do is slide images from left to right then you can probably use some jQuery plugin to achieve the same.Following is a URL on jQuery's animate() functionality :-

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate